# Magento webshopapps Matrixrate - more than one shipping method?

Tags: magento

i want to use Magento webshopapps Matrixrate to create the following shipping methods:

> 1. order from 0€-5€ = shipping cost 1,90€
> 2. order from 0€-5€ = shipping cost 4,90€

So the user can choose between the two shipping methods. But how can I do this with Matrixrate?
I have added these two lines in my csv file, but only one shipping method is displayed on the checkout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WebShopApps has an excellent Wiki Page that describes how to setup these extensions.

http://wiki.webshopapps.com/extensions/matrix-rates/examples

Towards the bottom of the link, download the matrixrates-pricevsdestination.csv. This is exactly what you are looking for.

Modify to fit your needs then upload to Magento Admin Panel under Shipping Settings

Comment: Is Possible Magento Allow Change shipping cost calculate by Individual Product weight instead of Package Weight?